# How to test angular controller with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine

Im new to jasmine unit testing and trying to test my login controller.

In the controller I have a login function that makes a post request to a servlet and it looks like that:

```
$http({ 
method: 'POST',
Url: loginSRV,
Data: 'userEmail' + $scope.User.Email+ '&' +'userPassword'+$scope.User.Password,
DataType:'text',
Headers:{'Content-Type': .....}
}).
success(function(data, status) {
$scope.status = status;
$scope.data=data; 
.
.
//doing something
.
.
}).
error(function(data, status){
.
.
//do something
.
.
});
```

My test looks like that:

```
describe('login test', function(){

beforeEach(module ('app'));

var scope;
var loginCTRL;

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
scope = $rootScope.$new();

createComtroller=function(){
return $controller('loginCTRL', {'$scope': scope
});
};
loginCTRL=createController();

}));

//Checking if the comtroller defined and some other tests

it("login", inject(function($controller){
scope.User = {};
scope.User.Password="1234";
scope.User.Email="a@b.c";

scope.Login();

expect(scope.data).toContain('success');
}));
.
.
.
});
```

Now when Im going into scope.login() with debugging is seems to go over the $http section and wont go in the success nor the error part.
I came to understand I have to mock the http response but I dont know how to do it and and am trying to avoid it but cant make my tests work...

Any ideas how can I test this controller?

Comment: The $http call is returning you a promise, have a look into mocking out promises in angular with jasmine - hint, look for using $q in your tests

Comment: Why do I need to use $q for? I thougt about using $httpBackend but cant get my mind around making it work